# How to Rest primary key

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I am developing asp.net application with sql server database.

I have table FinancialYear

```
caseno(unique)  finyear
1               2013-2014
2               2013-2014   
3               2013-2014 
1               2012-2013
2               2012-2013
3               2012-2013
```

For financial year-2013 to 2014. If I insert record ( select max(caseno) +1).

```
insert into finanancialYear values(max(caseno) +1,2013-2014)
```

If I delete record caseno:3  from the table, `select max(caseno)+1` will be 3
which is already deleted and again that record with caseno 3 will be inserted.

How  to solve the issue?

For every financial year in 'FinancialYear' table, caseno will be reset to 1 and if I add new record in finyear 2012-1013  then max(caseno) will be last value of caseno of that financial year 2012-2013

Again insert becomes

```
insert into finanancialYear values(max(caseno) +1,2012-2013)
```